# Django from Virtualenv Multiple processes running

Tags: python, django, bash, process, virtualenv

I'm running a local **django development server** together with **virtualenv** and it's been a couple of days that it behaves in a weird way. Sometimes I don't see any log in the console sometimes I see them.

A couple of times I've tried to quit the process and restart it and I've got the `port already taken` error, so I inspected the running process and there was still an instance of django running.
Other SO answers said that this is due to the *autoreload* feature, well so why sometimes I have no problem at all and sometimes I do?

Anyway For curiosity I `ps aux| grep python` and the result is always TWO running process, one from python and one from my activated "virtualenv" python:

`/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/python manage.py runserver
python manage.py runserver`

Is this supposed to be normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the mistery: Django was trying to send emails but it could not because of improper configuration, so it was hanging there forever trying to send those emails.

Most probably (I'm not sure here) Django calls an OS function or a subprocess to do so. The point is that the main process was forking itself and giving the job to a subprocess or thread, or whatever, I'm not expert in this.

It turns out that when your python is forked and you kill the father, the children can apparently keep on living after it.

Correct me if I'm wrong.